# Boost/Property Tree determine the value type

Tags: c++, boost, rpc, boost-propertytree, ice

I'd like to use Boost/Property Tree as a sort of synchronization with my application. 
To do this I'd planned to use Zeroc/ICE for state-synchronization *(using an Observe pattern and bidirectional connections)*.

However, to do this in an efficient way I need to somehow specify the I/O of the application *(obviously)*.

This works nicely for importing values into the tree *(since I can use InputStream to convert to any primitive type and catch occuring errors)* but it hampers when I want to export values.

With the functions exposed in the documentation I do not see any way to retrieve the actual type of an element

```
boost::property_tree::ptree Tree;

// Import
Ice::CommunicatorPtr communicator = current.adapter->getCommunicator();
Ice::InputStreamPtr in = Ice::createInputStream(communicator, item.data);

switch (item.type) {
    case BOOLVAL:
            double boolval;
            in->read(boolval);
            Tree.put(item.path, boolval);
            break;
}

// Export
// This is not possible since I cannot retrieve or compare the type
Ice::CommunicatorPtr communicator = current.adapter->getCommunicator();
Ice::OutputStreamPtr out = Ice::createOutputStream(communicator);
auto data = Tree.get<TYPE>(path);
out->write(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

The concept of a Property Tree provides hierarchical storage of data (key-value pairs) where the value is *text*.

That's it.

If your application assigns *meaning* to the contents of that text, the meta-data will have to be in your program. There is **no** variant leaf storage in the library.

This is also true even if the underlying serialization format (such as JSON) *does* support it, as the documentation clearly spells out, e.g.:

> - JSON values are mapped to nodes containing the value. However, all type information is lost; numbers, as well as the literals "null", "true" and "false" are simply mapped to their string form.

### What now?

It looks like you want to have a reflection-style framework, and Boost Property Tree doesn't provide it. I'd suggest other libraries but all of them either assume intrusive changes or still require you to model the meta-data for the program data manually.

Comment: Are there any libraries you could recommend? What should I further dig into? Thanks for clarification!

Comment: Qt has it. Protobuf. I personally like rolling my own basic things on top of Boost Fusion adapted structs. Boost Serialization is an option with some more code-writing. Of course with the means to have the meta-data in traits, you could conceivably use boost property tree, but you'd layer your semantics information on top of it